# Display Text Being Typed

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to develop a chat room for an Android App. I have a created some area for `EditText` and a corresponding button to `Enter` the text that is typed by a user.

On clicking on `Enter` I want to display the typed text on the same screen i.e. whatever text is being typed, it is subsequently being displayed on the same screen. I am using `Linear Layout(Horizontal)` for my app.

How can I implement this ?? Can someone help me with the code. I am totally new to Android Development Framework. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: What issues are you experiencing? What have you tried so far?

Comment: place 2 Edit text field 
one for input and other for out put 
get text from input edittext field in string and then place it in out put edit text field  
to get text from input edit text is like this 
string=input.gettext().toString();
and then place it output field Like 
output.settext(string);
simple

Comment: kk .. thanks Usman .. I think that might help.

Comment: Sweety .. please check ur answer once again .. I have posted a new query in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple. You create the xml file with one textView and one edittext and one button. Then you handle the event of button click in mainActivity and call onResume from it. Override the onResume so that you can update the textview.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
    EditText editBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBox1);
    String str = text.getText().toString();
    text.setText(str+" "+editBox.getText().toString());
    editBox.setText("");
    editBox.setHint("Type in here");

}
```

Comment: Did this work for you kamalbhai? Please accept answer which suited your requirement the best.

Comment: Sweety .. ur code works fine but the old text is not being displayed. It is being deleted .. I want to display the old text too. Please help ..

Comment: String str = text.getText().toString();
  text.setText(str+" "+editBox.getText().toString()); You can use this also save your previous text in database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Toast' to display the msg or use another 'TextView' which is set using 'setText()'

Answer (score 0):

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent"android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent">
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <EditText...
      <Button...
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
setContentView(R.Layout.main);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1); //Layout where you want to put your new dynamic TextView.

    String s=editText.getText().toString(); //Fetching String from your EditText
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setText(s);
    ll.addView(tv); //Add TextView inside the Layout.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an one editText for input and one TextView for displaying the typed message:

```
 tvChatWindow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvChatWindow);
 etInputWindow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInputWindow);        
 btnEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);

 btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // send message to other chat clients here

         //add a new line break character and the typed string to Chat Window
         tvChatWindow.append("\n" + etInputWindow.getText().toString());  

         //clear the text you have typed on the edittext
         etInputWindow.setText("");
     }
 });
```

Comment: Can you please check this code ? I am getting several errors from this code and I am unable to sort them out. Thanks.

Comment: which error did you get kamalbhai? I used these code in my project and they worked well.